# How do I write the CREATE TABLE statement that creates the target table from a SQL dump?

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql, create-table, dump

With a MySQL dump I have to create a dedicated MySQL database, import the SQL dump, which will create the source table and write the CREATE TABLE statement to create the target table.

As I did not have a MySQL instance on my machine I have installed a Cloud SQL storage.

I just imported the data, how to write the CREATE TABLE statement that creates the target table?

Here part of the .sql file

```
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!50503 SET NAMES utf8 */;
/*!40103 SET @OLD_TIME_ZONE=@@TIME_ZONE */;
/*!40103 SET TIME_ZONE='+00:00' */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO' */;
/*!40111 SET @OLD_SQL_NOTES=@@SQL_NOTES, SQL_NOTES=0 */;

--
-- Table structure for table `mail_events`
--

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `mail_events`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!50503 SET character_set_client = utf8mb4 */;
CREATE TABLE `mail_events` (
  `id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `email` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `timestamp` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `event` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `category` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `url` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `community_id` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `publication_id` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `announcement_id` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `lang` enum('fr','es','en','pt') CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `IDX__sendgridevents__timestamp` (`timestamp`),
  KEY `IDX__sendgridevents__category` (`category`),
  KEY `IDX__sendgridevents__user_id` (`user_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=406957428 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;

--
-- Dumping data for table `mail_events`
--

LOCK TABLES `mail_events` WRITE;
```

Comment: Open the dump in text editor and cut off needed CREATE TABLE statement.

Comment: Thanks @Akina, do you know where I have to put it in cloud-sql? I am new to this google tool

Comment: google cloud sql is just a platform to provide managed sql database instances. The database instance for you will still be mysql and you can use the standard mysql tools to interact with it.